# Cannot parameterize a stored procedure inside an SSIS

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, ssis, oledb

I'm creating an export ssis that takes a list of codes via Execute SQL Task, then the list is used in a Foreach Loop Container that has a data Flow Task inside. The Data flow task consists of two elements: an OLE DB Source that must execute a parameterized SP and Flat File Destination that must generate a TXT file.

Inside the ole DB Source I tried to parameterize a simple select and everything went smoothly, now I'm trying to parameterize an SP and I'm having problems currently I tried this code:

The field @PARAMETERS is composed as follows: ''HO','20230630',1,'FFV_CUMULATE'' instead the field @CODICE is the iterator of the foreach

So the SP would look like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP 
'HO','20230331',1,'FFV_CUMULATE','XXXX'
```

OLE DB Source is set to

```
EXEC [dbo].[SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP] ?, ?
WITH RESULT SETS(
(
@PARAMETERS AS NVARCHAR(500),
@CODICE AS NVARCHAR(500)
))
```

[image]

[image]

The error is from OLE DB Source using SQL Server Native Client 11 as the Connection Manager.

> Deferred prepare could not be completed
> Statement(s) could not be prepared
> Cannot retrieve column information from the data source

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is the result of you making up syntax for your [WITH RESULT SETS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#m-using-execute-to-redefine-a-single-result-set)

This is incorrect

```
EXEC [dbo].[SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP] ?, ?
WITH RESULT SETS(
(
@PARAMETERS AS NVARCHAR(500),
@CODICE AS NVARCHAR(500)
))
```

This is correct

```
EXEC [dbo].[SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP] ?, ?
WITH RESULT SETS(
(
PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(500),
CODICE NVARCHAR(500)
))
```

Now, I can parameterize my query

[image]

You'll notice I changed the syntax slightly. When I used the `EXEC ... ?,?` format, I was hit with

> The SQL command requires a parameter named "@input1", which is not found in the parameter mapping.

I was too lazy to look into why and created SQL variables and initialized them from the SSIS parameters and then let them roll into the proc. I assume the error is based on the nested single quotes but again, lazy, since I have an approach that works.

```
declare @input1 nvarchar(500) = ?
, @input2 nvarchar(500) = ?;

EXEC [dbo].[SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP] @input1, @input2
WITH RESULT SETS(
(
PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(500),
CODICE NVARCHAR(500)
));
```

The way I figured out you had the wrong syntax in your query was by testing it in a query tool. It highlighted exactly what was wrong.

I created a minimal reproduction of what your stored procedure might look like. All I or SSIS cares about is the metadata that is the input and the shape of the output

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP
(
   @input1 nvarchar(500)
,  @input2 nvarchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @input1 As [Parameters], @input2 As [Codice];
END
```

Testing then becomes a cinch

```
DECLARE @input1 nvarchar(500) = 'x'
,@input2 nvarchar(500) = 'y';

EXEC [dbo].[SSIS_EXPORT_SQUAREUP] @input1, @input2
WITH RESULT SETS(
(
PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(500),
CODICE NVARCHAR(500)
));
```

Running that yields the expected output

[image]